# I always get the last wifiInfo. How can I get the current wifiInfo

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

When connecting to wifi, I always get the last `wifiInfo`. For example, the phone is connected to wifi-a now, then I start the program and the phone connects to wifi-b, but what I get is wifi-a `wifiInfo`. How can I fix it?
thank you

```
@Override
public void run() {
    if (wifiConnectFlag == 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "connect wifi start...");
        wifiAdmin = new WifiAdmin(getApplicationContext());
        wifiAdmin.openWifi();
        boolean b = wifiAdmin.disconnectWifi();
        Log.d(TAG, "run: "+b);
        WifiConfiguration wificon = wifiAdmin.CreateWifiInfo("MERCURY_954F4C", "", 1);
        wifiAdmin.addNetwork(wificon);
        wifiConnectFlag = 1;
        Log.e(TAG, "connect successed");
        String ssid = wifiAdmin.getSSID();
        String bssid = wifiAdmin.getBSSID();
        int id = wifiAdmin.getNetworkId();
        String ipString = wifiAdmin.intToIp(wifiAdmin.getIPAddress());
        Log.e("IP", "ip: "+ipString+" id: "+id+" ssid: "+ssid+" bssid: "+bssid);
        //Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(wifiAdmin.getIPAddress()));            
    }
}
```